# UIAlertView Button action causing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am displaying a `UIAlertView` to the user with an "OK" button on it, and when the user presses the button I would like my delegate method to perform an action. However currently when the user presses the "OK" button the application crashes with this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb)
```

Here is my code, the alert view shows fine with the button etc, however as soon as the button is pressed this is the error I am getting. It's almost like a breakpoint but if I click the forward button nothing happens.

```
//.h
@interface ErrorHandling : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate> {


//.m
#define myAlertViewsTag 0

- (void)recivedErrorCode:(int)errorCode MethodName:(NSString *)methodName {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case 1: {
            NSLog(@"ERROR = 1");
            message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error 1:"
                                                 message:@"The supplied registration code does exist."
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [message show];
        }
            break;
        case 2: {
            NSLog(@"ERROR = 2");
            message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error 2:"
                                                 message:@"Your registration is no longer valid."
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
            message.tag = myAlertViewsTag;
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [message show];
        }
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (message.tag == myAlertViewsTag) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            // Do something when ok pressed
            NSLog(@"DONE 1");
        } else {
            // Do something for ok
            NSLog(@"DONE 2");
        }
    } else {
        // Do something with responses from other alertViews
        NSLog(@"DONE 3");
    }
}
```

**update**:
This is how I call the class the code above is in from my conneciton class.

```
 // Do whatever you need to with the error number
 ErrorHandling *errorHandling = [[ErrorHandling alloc] init];
 [errorHandling recivedErrorCode:errorRecivedFromServerInt MethodName:methodName];
```

Comment: How do you manage the lifetime of your `ErrorHandling` instance?

Comment: Are you declaring "message" in .h file and reusing it? Why do you not declare it locally?

Comment: I am declaring it in .h I did this because I thought I needed to access it in the delegate method.

Comment: @CarlVeazey It is called from another class, check updated question I Have added the code I use to request this error class at the bottom of the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the lifetime of your `ErrorHandling` instance. You create an instance and then call the `recivedErrorCode:` method. After that there are no other strong references to your `errorHandling` instance so it gets deallocated.

Meanwhile the alert view has made the instance its delegate. When you tap the button on the alert view, the alert view tries to contact its delegate. But the delegate has been deallocated and now points to garbage memory resulting in the crash.

The solution is to keep a longer lasting strong reference to the `ErrorHandling` instance. At least until after the alert view is dismissed.

BTW - Your method name has a typo - it should be `receivedErrorCode:`.

Comment: okay, I understand that but dont really know a way of keeping the instance for longer... I will research it now but any tips would be welcomed.

Comment: Use an instance variable.

Comment: yup I just realised after reading your answer again. This worked by declaring it as a strong instance in my header file. Thanks a bunch for this.

Comment: Why is it in the .h file? Are other classes going to make use of this variable? If not, declare it in the .m file so it is private.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear from this code if this line:

```
   if (message.tag == myAlertViewsTag)...
```

Actually points to anything valid. Is the message object still around even... I think you problems lies there, somewhere. Post more code that helps us understand this if you want more help.

Comment: currently its not even making it to the method.

Answer (score 0):

In alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: you are checking the alert view's tag by using "message.tag".

It looks like you were intending for message to be an ivar in your class. A better way that should also solve your bad_access would be to use the alert view that is passed into the didDismissWithButtonIndex, rather than retaining the UIAlertView in your class. This code should do the trick:

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == myAlertViewsTag) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            // Do something when ok pressed
            NSLog(@"DONE 1");
        } else {
            // Do something for ok
            NSLog(@"DONE 2");
        }
    } else {
        // Do something with responses from other alertViews
        NSLog(@"DONE 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly this still didnt work, I think rmaddy is onto it with respect to me loosing my instance.. I need to look into that now.